# keep on getting error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'concat' of undefined

Tags: jquery, json

```
$.when(
          $.getJSON('pathto/test/collection.json'),
          $.getJSON('pathto/test/ad.json')
        ).then(function(collection, advertised){

            var items = collection.collections.concat(advertised.advertised);
            alert(items);
        });
```

It gave alert message: `[object Object],success,[object Object],[object Object],success,[object Object]`

Two JSON files (URLs)

```
{
      "advertised": [
        { "title": "Rabbit",
          "subtitle": "Nibble",
          "advertised": true
         },
        { "title": "Dog",
          "subtitle": "Woof",
          "advertised": true
        },
        { "title": "Cat",
          "subtitle": "Purr",
          "advertised": true
        }
      ]
    }

{
      "collections": [
        { "title": "Horse",
          "subtitle": "Na~~",
          "advertised": false
        },
        { "title": "Turkey",
          "subtitle": "Gobble",
          "advertised": false
        },
        { "title": "Goat",
          "subtitle": "Baaaa",
          "advertised": false
        },
        { "title": "Snake",
          "subtitle": "hissssss",
          "advertised": false
        }
      ]
}
```

Have been trying to combine these data from 2 json files in 1 so i could use var items to display title, name, etc. Keep on getting the same error.

Help appreciated!

Comment: Are you trying to combine the two jsons? or something else..? what is the expected structure of items after the operation?

Comment: You're saying you're getting an error and the alert at the same time. If `concat` is throwing error, you won't get the alert. Since the alert is working, there is no error. Please provide a an example demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this is what you're trying to achieve:

```
$.when(
    $.getJSON('collection.json'),
    $.getJSON('ad.json')
).then(function(collection, advertised){
    var items = collection[0].collections.concat(advertised[0].advertised);
    alert(JSON.stringify(items));
});
```

I've used JSON.stringify in the alert only so that you can look inside the JSON object. Otherwise the alert will simply show [object Object]..